# Exchanging Limits in Series inversion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

I have the Lagrange Bürmann formula as follows: 
$$\sum^{m-1}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n!}(w-b)^n\lim_{z \rightarrow a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left(f^{'}(z)\frac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right)^n$$

Where g(z) is the function you are finding the inverse of, and f(z) is the function you will compose the inverse with if you so choose.

My question is, when is it okay to switch the limit and the differentiation? I tried to do it with g(z) = $e^x - 1$ and f(x) = x, and I obtained the appropriate series for ln(x+1).

Comment: What is the expression you have a formula *for*?  Is there an *equation* lurking in the background?

Comment: @RobertLewis the formula takes a function $g(z)$ and finds $f(g^{-1}(a))$ as a taylor series.

Comment: I think that maybe http://bit.ly/1lt08zn answers my question, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure either; worth thinking about in any event!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're asking when $$\lim_{z \rightarrow a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left(f^{'}(z)\frac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right)^n = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \lim_{z \rightarrow a} \left(f^{'}(z)\frac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)}\right)^n $$?  After taking the limit on the right-hand side the result would be constant with respect to $z$ and so would just have derivative=zero, so in general you can never switch the limit and the derivatives.

Comment: What I did for $e^z - 1$ was $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(f^{'}(z)\frac{z-a}{g(z+h)-g(z)}\right)^n$$

Which I felt was correct(and got me the correct answer) but I have no way to justify it(or knowing if getting the correct answer was just a fluke)